# Все свойства css в json

Tags: html

Пишу что то вроде визуального редактора кода. 
Вопрос.
Если ли где то все свойства css с их всеми возможными значениями в json или xml?
Мне это нужно для создания подсказок в редакторе

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет разница `getComputedStyle` от пустого и интересующего Вас элемента:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.block').forEach(el => el.onclick = e => {
  let dummy = document.createElement(el.tagName);
  document.body.append(dummy);
  let dummyStyles = getComputedStyle(dummy);
  let styles = Object.entries(getComputedStyle(el));
  ta.textContent = styles.filter(s => s[1] !== dummyStyles[s[0]])
                         .map(s => s.join(': '))
                         .join('\n')
  dummy.remove();                       
})
```

```css
.block{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background-color:red;
}

.two {
  border:solid;
}

#ta {
  height:115px;
  width:550px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id=ta ></textarea><br>
<div tabindex="1" class="block one"></div>
<div tabindex="2" class="block two"></div>
```